# How can I recover the files from an eUFS in my broken laptop?

Tags: file-recovery, samsung-ssd

My Samsung Galaxy Book S (model "NP767XCM", bought in 2020) won't charge!

When I plug in a charger, the status LED light blinks blue twice (sometimes once or twice more) and the screen turns on for precisely 16 seconds (while only showing an empty battery image, "0%", and a timer).

I opened up my laptop and removed the internal battery. When I plugged the charger back in, the screen said "State unknown" along with an image of a "?" inside of a battery. Re-attaching the battery produces the same behavior as before.

I'm now looking to recover my files. This laptop uses "embedded universal flash storage" (eUFS). **Is it possible to take out that component and plug it into some reader / adapter?**

One problem is that my motherboard is covered in some black "tape" and I can't identify the eUFS.

[This video disassembles my model](https://youtu.be/xxWIkRYfyRc?t=194) and the motherboard is only partially covered by "tape" in the center. Maybe it's easier to identify the eUFS here.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Replacing the battery might work -- though that small battery seems to be going for US$60 or more. Perhaps you could figure out the pin-out of the battery connector, and cobble together an equivalent to an actual battery, for short-term use, just to get files off.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik That sounds very promising... Do you maybe have any guidance / resources to suggest on how to accomplish this? I'm not very skilled with electronics.

Comment: @Tsiolkovsky, it's not rocket science, but does require a knowledge of electronics. Perhaps data recovery would be best left to a repair place.

Comment: I'll look into your idea a bit further, I have some tiny knowledge and tools laying around. Thank you for suggesting it, sir.